# Common place to load requirejs config

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs

I am making a hybrid application with SPA and Mvc 3. Now what i require is to load different pages with condition configs in backbone .

I have loaded my main file with like this

```
require
paths:
    jquery:'Libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min'
    underscore:'Libs/Underscore/underscore.min'
    backbone:'Libs/Backbone/backbone-min'
    text:'Libs/Requirejs/text'
    bootstrap:'Libs/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
    jqValidation:'Libs/jquery/jquery.validate.min'
    jqValUnobtrusive : 'Libs/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min'

shim:
    'underscore':
        exports : '_'
    'backbone':
        deps: ["underscore"]
        exports:'Backbone'
    'bootstrap': 
        deps : ['jquery']
        exports : 'jquery'
    'jqValidation':
        deps : ['jquery']
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.validate'
    'jqValUnobtrusive':
        deps: ['jquery', 'jqValidation']
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.validate.unobtrusive'

require ["App/app","backbone",'bootstrap'] ,(App,Backbone)->
app = new App()
Backbone.history.start()
```

Now this same set of config is required in other files also . Now how to load this config in each and every main.coffee file where I require ? I dont want this config to be redundant . Just one place I want to put it and then call it to other places . How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Loading your require config from a single shared module is a very good plan.

This is the method I use. Different pages and my build system all use the same config file.
The tradeoff is you have to nest your require dependencies, but it's been worth for me.

#### Index.html, or any other page

```
<script>
    require(['require_config'], function () {
        require(['core'], function (core) {
            window._app = core.start();
        });
    })
</script>
```

#### require_config.coffee

```
define [], () ->
  require.config
    packages: [
      'core'
      'dashboard/widgets/base'
    ]
    paths:        
      # 3rd Party Bower Libraries
      handlebars: "bower_components/require-handlebars-plugin/Handlebars"
      underscore: "bower_components/underscore-amd/underscore"
      jqueryui: "bower_components/jquery-ui/jqueryui"
    shim:
      bootstrap:
        deps: [ 'jquery' ]
        exports: 'jquery'
      markdown:
        exports: 'markdown'
```